# Which Flutter Firebase Auth operations can trigger the "requires-recent-login" error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Flutter project that integrates Firebase Auth for user authentication. I've encountered the "requires-recent-login" error while interacting with Firebase Auth, and I'd like to understand better which specific operations within Flutter can lead to this error.

The error is raised when the user attempts an operation that requires a recent login. However, I'm interested in knowing the comprehensive list of Firebase Auth operations in Flutter that could potentially trigger this error.

Could anyone provide a detailed breakdown of all the Firebase Auth operations in Flutter that have the potential to result in the "requires-recent-login" error? This would greatly help me in identifying potential points of failure and implementing appropriate error handling in my application.

Comment: "I'm aware that the error occurs when a user attempts to access protected resources while their session has expired" This is not true. The error is raised when the user attempts an operation that requires a recent login. If an unexpired session attempts an operation that requires a more recent login than it has, it will (as I also said in my answer to your previous question) still raise the "requires-recent-login" error. The only way to handle this error is to catch it, get the credentials from the user, and try it again.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, you are right. I will update my question so as not to create confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation on [re-authenticating a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user), indicates:

> Some security-sensitive actions — such as **deleting an account, setting a primary email address, and changing a password** — require that the user has recently signed in.

This was likely the exhaustive list when this documentation was written, but it could well be outdated by now.

I did a quick scan of the Android documentation (platform chosen because it has the most type information), and found that most of the use of the relevant `FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException` in methods in the [`FirebaseUser` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser).

I don't think there's an exhaustive list though. It's a valid request, so I recommend leaving feedback through the link at the bottom of the documentation, but for now you'll probably have to scour the code and scan documentation pages like I did.